# Rudin Real and Complex Analysis - Baire's Category Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, baire-category

I have been trying to understand Rudin's proof of Baire's Category theorem and I think I understood most of it except eqn (2), where he mentions $0 \leq r_1 \leq 1$, and later generalizes this to $0 \leq r_n \leq 1/n$. My understanding of open set $X$ is that for every $x \in X$, there exists $r > 0$ such that $B(x, r) \subset X$. So how can we know that $0 \leq r_n \leq 1/n$? This inequality is important since this helps us to determine that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy. I know I'm missing something and I would really appreciate much clarity on this concept.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If $\varepsilon_n$ is such that$$\overline{S(x_n,\varepsilon_n)}\subset V_n\cap S(x_{n-1},\varepsilon_{n-1}),$$let $r_n=\left\{\varepsilon,\frac1n\right\}$. Then $r_n\leqslant\frac1n$ and$$\overline{S(x_n,r_n)}\subset V_n\cap S(x_{n-1},r_{n-1}).$$